# toolbar goes up when keyboard opens xamarin forms

Tags: android, keyboard, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I want to keep toolbar visible on top while displaying soft keyboard. I tried all options with windowSoftInputMode but non of them worked. This has started occurring after upgrading xamarin forms to 2.3.4.247. It was working fine previously.

[Before xamarin forms update Previous result](http://gph.is/2uRYsw5)

[After xamarin forms update result](http://gph.is/2whGW8h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code in MainActivity solved my issue.

Ref: https://gist.github.com/jimmgarrido/e36033b26f01e8da091fd321d41d991a

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        //Remove the status bar underlay in API 21+
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
            var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(18, 52, 86, 255));
        }


        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    }
```